# How to make a request for each item in the first HTTP response using RxJs with redux observable?

Tags: redux, rxjs, xmlhttprequest, observable, redux-observable

I have two microservices (Users and Payments), I want to fetch users with their payments.
So first i fetch users from Users microservice (GET /users/):

```
[{userId: 1, name: 'john', ...}, {userId: 2, name: 'mark', ...}, {userId: 3, name: 'bob', ...}]
```

Then I want to fetch payments for each user. I need to send a request to the payments microservice (GET /payments/userId)

Expected result.-

```
[
  {userId: 1, name: 'john', ..., payments: [1,2,3]},
  {userId: 2, name: 'mark', ..., payments: [2,3,4]},
  {userId: 3, name: 'bob', ..., payments: [3,4,5]}
]
```

I have this code to fetch users.

```
const fetchUsersEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USERS).flatMap(action =>
    Observable.concat(
      Observable.of(actions.loading(true)),
      Observable.fromPromise(usersService.getUsers())
        .flatMap(response =>

          //I need to fetch payments for each user first              

          Observable.concat(
            Observable.of(actions.loading(false)),
            Observable.of(actions.fetchUsersFulfilled(response)),
          ))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(actions.loading(false))),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your services return a promise? You could try like this

Try like this:

```
users = await usersService.getUsers();
users = users.map(user => ({
  ...user,
  payments: await paymentsService.getPayments(user.userId),
}));
```